# Using XDoclet to generate openejb-jar.xml,result is empty

Tags: openejb, xdoclet

Here is my annotations in my managerBean:

```
/**
 * @ejb:bean name="TestManagerBean" type="Stateless"
 *           transaction-type="Container" view-type="remote"
 * @ejb:interface generate="none"
 *                remote-class="com.spokesoft.component.cost.ejb.TestManager"
 * @ejb:home generate="none"
 *           remote-class="com.spokesoft.component.cost.ejb.TestManagerHome"
 * @ejb:ejb-ref ejb-name="TestBean" ref-name="Test/CostEntity"
 * @ejb:transaction type="Required"
 * @ejb:resource-ref res-name="TestData" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
 *                   res-auth="Container"
 */
```

When I use XDoclet to generate openejb-jar.xml,it just generate a xml file with a root node of openejb-jar . Is there any problem with my Xdoclet annotation?